# How do you find the right saddle for road biking?

Tags: bike-fit, saddle, road

I bought a Cube Attain GTRC disc, a great bike apart from the saddle, which is quite chunky and square.

I would like to find a better one.  Tips for saddle sizing for road biking?

- Long saddle versus short
- Cut out or not
- thin versus thick
- measurement of sit bones? how?
- material?
- brands?
- length of ride

I once went to the cycle show and sat on a special seat that displaced blue gel and showed the shape of my arse. Is this recommended? Not sure if I will find these in IKEA though.

Comment: you become a prolific buyer and seller of saddles on ebay burning through £1000's in the search of the 'right' saddle.  Finally, just when all hope is lost, you find one that is perfect - unfortunately, it is also discontinued, so next time you need a saddle you will need to start the whole process all over again.

Comment: @AndyP - when you find just the right one and discovered it's been discontinued, you continue your scouring of all known sources to buy a 2nd one right away!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is very much like with shoes: very personal. You look for one until you find it and then you use the same model for as long as possible.

Or, one can use service of a tailor, or in this case, bike fit expert, for a price. Sit bones measurement is one of the most affordable things, as a simple [cardboard](https://www.bike-components.de/en/SQlab/Measuring-Cardboard-to-Measure-Sit-Bone-Width-p20171/) can be used for that.

[image: cardboard]

For complex cases, a custom saddle can be molded specially for you. See an article by Lennard Zinn at [VeloNews](https://www.velonews.com/2018/10/bikes-and-tech/technical-faq/technical-faq-happiness-is-a-custom-saddle_479999).

Comment: it is a bit like that evolution of humankind t-shirt

Comment: except going from aero to upright is devolution :)